# How to display data in column in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project I am trying to display data in td, the data is coming from backend and that data is coming in console. But I am not able to display data in table.

For this project I am using functional Component

This is my Child.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Child() {
    const [oldEmployData, newEmployData] = useState([])

    async function getEmploysData() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:1000/api/employList');
            newEmployData(response.data);
            console.log(response.data)
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getEmploysData()
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-12'>
                    <table className="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Employ Name</th>
                                <th>Employ Age</th>
                                <th>Employ Stream</th>
                                <th>Employ Address</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

If I am clear please put a comment
```

Comment: Use map to iterate over data from backend and return row inside tbody.

Comment: You need to map your data to table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your axios request is responding with a valid JSON array, you can render that data directly into your table via `Array#map()` by extending your render logic as shown below:

```
<tbody>
    {data.map(item => 
    <tr key={item.id}>
        {/* assuming each item in JSON array has firstName, lastName, email
            and password fields */}
        <td>{item.firstName}</td>
        <td>{item.lastName}</td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>{item.password}</td>
        {/* suppose you have editItem() and deleteItem() defined, these
            can be invoked (during click event) for each item like this */}
        <td>
            <button className="btn btn-primary" 
                    onClick={() => editItem(item)}>Edit</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button className="btn btn-danger"
                    onClick={() => deleteItem(item)}>Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>)} 
</tbody>
```

An important point to note is that each `<tr>` element being mapped must have a `key` prop supplied with a value that is [unique to the item being rendered/mapped](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). With that in mind, the assumption being made above is that each item in the `data`  array has a unique `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose json data like this

```
    let data = [
    {id:1,name:'One'},
    {id:2,name:'Two'},
    {id:3,name:'Three'}
   ]
```

Iterate like this

```
   {data.map(d=>
    <tr key={d.id}>
     <td>{d.name}</td>
     <td>{}</td>
     <td>{}</td>
     <td></td>
     <td><button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={()=>handleEdit(d.id)>Edit</button></td>
     <td><button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={()=>handleDelete(d.id)}>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
    )}
```